# How to call all() on a Mongoose::Join object

Tags: perl, moose

I use mongoose to set up the following (simplified and compacted) data model:

```
package Model::Tag;
use Moose; 
use Mongoose::Class; with 'Mongoose::Document';
has 'value'         => (is  => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1);
no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package Model::Document;
use Moose; 
use Mongoose::Class; with 'Mongoose::Document';
has 'title'         => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1);
has_many 'tags'     => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Model::Tag');
no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

The important parts of my test are:

```
package main;
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $expected; my $got;

my $doc = Model::Document->new(title => 'My new document with many tags');
my $tag1 = Model::Tag->new(value => 'foo');
my $tag2 = Model::Tag->new(value => 'bar');

my $x1 = $doc->tags->add($tag1);
my $x2 = $doc->tags->add($tag2);

# print "x1 = $x1 x2 = $x2 \n";

my $document_tags = $doc->tags;
print Dumper $document_tags;

can_ok($document_tags, 'all');

my $tag_array_ref = $document_tags->all();
```

Now the problem:

The dumped output of $document_tags is a Mongoose::Join object:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'delete_buffer' => {},
             'with_class' => 'Model::Tag',
             'buffer' => {
                           '58102804' => bless( {
                                                  'value' => 'foo'
                                                }, 'Model::Tag' ),
                           '58069732' => bless( {
                                                  'value' => 'bar'
                                                }, 'Model::Tag' )
                         }
           }, 'Mongoose::Join' );
```

And the documentation about [Mongoose::Join](http://search.cpan.org/~rodrigo/Mongoose-0.23/lib/Mongoose/Join.pm) lists the METHODS:

```
add, remove, find, find_one, first, all, hash_on, hash_array, query, collection, with_collection_name
```

but calling

```
$document_tags->all();
```

causes an error

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at C:/Perl/site/lib/Mongoose.pm line 132.
```

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is coming from Mongoose, not your test program directly.  Line 132 of Mongoose.pm from the most recent version of Mongoose (0.23) is in the method that establishes a connection to MongoDB.

Following that lead, I then noticed that your test code doesn't include a call to `Mongoose->db()`.  This is needed in order to specify the database to connect to.  After adding that and trying your test program, I also noticed that your document wasn't saved to MongoDB first before attempting to retrieve attributes (i.e., the tags) from it.

Here is your test code with the changes I made to resolve the problem.  The key bits start with the line `# Connect to database`.

```
package Model::Tag;
use Moose;
use Mongoose::Class; with 'Mongoose::Document';
has 'value'         => (is  => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1);
no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package Model::Document;
use Moose;
use Mongoose::Class; with 'Mongoose::Document';
has 'title'         => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1);
has_many 'tags'     => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Model::Tag');
no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $doc = Model::Document->new(title => 'My new document with many tags');
my $tag1 = Model::Tag->new(value => 'foo');
my $tag2 = Model::Tag->new(value => 'bar');

my $x1 = $doc->tags->add($tag1);
my $x2 = $doc->tags->add($tag2);

my $document_tags = $doc->tags;
print Dumper $document_tags;

# Connect to database
Mongoose->db('foo');
# and save our document first
$doc->save();

# now we can retrieve the array (note, not array ref) of tags
my @tag_array = $document_tags->all();
print Dumper(\@tag_array);
```

Comment: I know about how to store the values in the Mongodb. But I did not expect that I have to store the values to be able to read them again. Thats strange

Comment: It appears to follows from a literal reading of the `Mongoose::Join` docs -- `all` is a wrapper for `find`, which in turn queries MongoDB.  It doesn't check the buffer of unsaved documents added by `add`; whether it should is a question for the maintainer of Mongoose.

Comment: Yes, but the maintainer recomends asking on Stackoverflow. :-(

Comment: The maintainer sending you to Stackoverlow seems like an odd way to do it, since at this point the question seems to have morphed into one about the module's design and purpose, which seems a little too hypothetical.

Going back to the concrete question of usage patterns for Mongoose, it looks like `save()`ing early and often is the way to go.

Comment: I'm still not happy with the solution. Accessing values from the object should be independent from the internal save status.